# Post-hack authentication hell on Facebook - help?

Tags: facebook

My mom's FB account was compromised. The attacker created a new account, and associated her email with the new, bogus account. We'll call that "BA". The attacker changed the password, email and phone number associated with the original account ("OA"), which makes it impossible for her to recover it.

We reported it hacked and uploaded a copy of her passport weeks ago, but received no response.

Now we tried to just give up, and use the BA as her new active account. When we tried to change the name on BA to match her actual name, FB says, "Approve your login on another computer". I'm sitting here with another computer logged into her account, but there's no prompt to approve a login. So we can't recover the OA, can't repurpose the BA, and she's lost all her photos, contacts, and history.

Has anybody figured a way out of this authentication hell?

Answer (score 0):

Weirdly, after a while, FB simply stopped asking for approval from another computer. Never found a way to actually approve a login.

She remains totally locked out of her original account, but is seems to be able to use the repurposed bogus account.